# Is converting a Kotlin file to java, adding java code to it and converting back to Kotlin same as adding code directly to the Kotlin file?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to contribute to a Kotlin android project on Github, but I don't know Kotlin. Supposing I convert the Kotlin code to Java using 'Decompile' in Android Studio, add my own java code to the converted file and then convert the edited file back to Kotlin. Will the resulting Kotlin code be the same if I directly added code to it without conversion to java?
    Is this a feasible strategy if I want to contribute to a Kotlin project without knowing Kotlin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Kotlin decompiler is *not* for converting Kotlin code back to Java and actually using that code. It's to give you an idea of what bytecode your Kotlin code is compiled to, only with the familiar Java syntax, since most people can't read the bytecode directly. The decompiled Java code often isn't even executable without putting in additional work to fix it.

The Java to Kotlin compiler *is* meant to give you working Kotlin code from existing Java code, however, even that can't produce nice, idiomatic Kotlin.

Combining these two imperfect conversions (if it somehow works) will not get you to the original Kotlin code with just your new modifications, it's likely to mess all the converted code up significantly. For an analogue, think of it as translating a sentence with Google Translate through several different languages, and then going back to the original.

If you wish to contribute to an open source project that uses Kotlin, it's much easier and much more feasible to just learn Kotlin. It's really quite easy to pick it up if you already know Java.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with zsmb13.

It's not a great idea to perform the following steps:

1. Inspect Kotlin Byte Code
2. Convert Byte Code to Java
3. Edit Java Code
4. Convert Java Code to Kotlin

You would end up with something close to nonsense and you certainly wouldn't get clean, idiomatic Kotlin code.

If you have a background in Java development, it shouldn't take you long to get up to speed with Kotlin.  I find it a very clean and expressive language which removes much of Java's unnecessary boilerplate.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said converting Kotlin to Java simply to edit the code in Java and then convert it back to Kotlin, does not make any sense.  If you are simply looking to edit existing Kotlin code, you should learn Kotlin and edit the Kotlin code.

However since Java can be seamlessly called from Kotlin, if you have some fantastic Java library or class that would really fill in a gap in an existing Kotlin project,  you might be able to contribute the Java code directly.  Assuming the project is not targeting Kotlin Native, and is not strictly disallowing Java,  they could make use of your existing Java code, and then convert it to Kotlin, when the time comes that it needs to be modified.

Many organizations are following the formula that all **new** code is to be written in Kotlin, and existing Java code only be converted to Kotlin when it needs to be changed, so it's perfectly reasonable that a Kotlin project might contain or at the very least use Java code via referenced libraries.